# WP Cron job timeout issues

Tags: php, wp-cron, cron

I have to run a php function for around 10 minutes. Now I am sheduling the job as a wp-cron-job. But it is getting timed out after 30seconds which is the maximum execution time for php. How to get rid of this timeout issue?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion function that works 10min is not a best idea. Can You maybe refactor Your function or simply try to build `batch processing`?

My favorite article about that: https://pippinsplugins.com/batch-processing-for-big-data/

Answer (score 0):

30 seconds should be enough for a script in the web, but that's generally speaking.

Running your cron as php-cli will have no timeout limit, you can read more about this [here](https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/wordpress/real-cron-job/)

You can also increase the timeout in any php script, as discussed here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829403/how-to-increase-the-execution-timeout-in-php already.

Comment: I'm running my cron-job exactly as described in your first link, and it's getting a timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Here is also ready-made class for you to extend and batch process elegantly - https://github.com/gdarko/wp-batch-processing

I used it to run a big batch process on customers, and it's working great.

https://github.com/gdarko/wp-batch-processing

Here is an article about it

https://wptutspro.com/batch-processing-as-background-tasks/